# Sweeten/Fix Eggnog

Tags: eggs, cream, sweeteners

I made some non-alcoholic eggnog using the same recipe I had previously used but this time it came out too eggy (tastes a bit like tapioca but too much egg taste, even for eggnog). Is there a quick or easy fix to sweeten the eggnog to balance the eggy taste? Is adding sugar the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugar won't dissolve enough.

You should use a simple syrup. 
Equal parts sugar and water, boiled to dissolve then cooled.

I get that eggy flavor in my eggnog when I overcook it. Another way to try and mask it is to add more rum flavoring.

Comment: I made a 1/2 cup syrup and it was better, do you by chance know a ratio or is it more guess work since it probably got over-cooked?

Comment: I don't know a good ratio. I do it to taste.